# View Controller get stuck on calling unwind segue in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a bit complex hierarchy of calling multiple VC's and then at the end unwind to particular VC again, My flow is like this,
I have a VC that opens with these two conditions,

```
HomeVC -> DetailVC -> VC1 -> An API call to check if data exist, if yes then present ListVC if not then present Form VC
```

If `FormVC` is opened then after submitting form i have to show `ListVC`
If `ListVC` is opened first then it simply present `Form VC`, as in UI `ListVC` comes first and `FormVC` is the second one.
Now when i comes directly from `FormVC` to `DetailVC`through unwind segue, detail vc screen get stuck, now action is performed on it neither it scrolls. I'm too much confused why it is showing such behaviour. How i can fix it? why it is stuck my app?

This is how i call Unwind segue in `DetailVC`,

```
@IBAction func unwindToPropertyDetail(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{

}
```

and in `FormVC`, I just performSegue method like this to come on DetailVC,

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GoToDetails", sender: self)
```

Comment: Can you prepare some test app to show us how it's look like in the code and upload it i.e. on github?

Comment: What do you do in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` of `DetailVC`?

Comment: I call and API that bring data for Detail VC screen, in ViewWillAppear method. @Paulw11

Comment: It will take time for this, if you have any question regarding flow i can explain to you. @Michcio

Comment: When i fill FormVC and then present LIst VC through presenting VC method. @Michcio

Comment: I suggest you set some breakpoints and see what you app is doing.

Comment: i have placed breakpoints also, i think it might be due to presenting and dismissing VC's multiple times and overlapping of that might be causing this issue, Like as i said FormVC comes second and ListVC comes first in UI, so when i fill the FormVC then i present the ListVC, might be this causing issue? .@Paulw11

Comment: if i want to show first VC which is ListVC after submitting FormVC which is second VC, should i present ListVC ? .@Paulw11

Answer (score 0):

Have you try using dispatch queue?

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your answer to add some explanation and details.

Comment: dispatch queue where? @Ritesh Patel